# why the GridView.custom did not rerender in flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview

I am uisng `GridView.custom` to render four Grid in the sreen in flutter(`v3.0.4`), this is the core render dart code look like:

```
Widget buildGridView(List<TodoTask> renderTasks) {
    return GridView.custom(
      semanticChildCount: 2,
      cacheExtent: 4,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        mainAxisSpacing: 3.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 3.0,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: childAspectRatio.value,
      ),
      childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index) {
        List<TodoTask> itemsBuild = renderTasks.where((element) => element.priority == index + 1).toList();
        return buildListViewItemWidget(index, itemsBuild);
      }, childCount: 4),
    );
  }
```

the render function will be invoke 2 times, fisrt the page initial render, the tasks size are 0. The next time when the async request fetched the tasks from server side, invoke this function to rerender the widget. To my surprise, the second time execute but did not trigger the `GridView.custom` rerender. why did this happen? Am I missing something? what should I do to let the `GridView.custom` rerender after fetched data from server side? I set the breakpoint in childrenDelegate code block, the sencond invoke enter the  `buildGridView` function but did not trigger the breakpoint in `childrenDelegate`. I have tried like this:

```
Widget buildGridView(List<TodoTask> renderTasks) {
    if (renderTasks.isEmpty) {
      return Text("Loading....");
    }
    return GridView.custom(
      semanticChildCount: 2,
      cacheExtent: 4,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        mainAxisSpacing: 3.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 3.0,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: childAspectRatio.value,
      ),
      childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index) {
        List<TodoTask> itemsBuild = renderTasks.where((element) => element.priority == index + 1).toList();
        return buildListViewItemWidget(index, itemsBuild);
      }, childCount: 4),
    );
  }
```

when the `renderTasks` is null, render the loading..., seems still did not enter the `childrenDelegate`.

BTW：seems like the controller did not contains buildContext. I am put this code in the get `get: ^4.3.8` controller code.

Comment: I am not sure. Can you show the parent 
widget  of the buildGridView

Answer (score 0):

Sliverchildbuilderdelegate will build it lazily. Maybe thats the reason. Its not build till it needs to be displayed. Try other delegates like sliverchildlistdelegate